# Standard matrix for linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwQyC.png)

I am having a hard time understanding where the matrix for $e_1, e_2 $ and therefor $T(e_1) , T(e_2) are coming from.  If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.  I understand everything else, I just can't get started.

Comment: In general (in row vector form) we have $e_i = [0,...,0,1,0,...0]$, i.e. $e_i$ is the vector that has a $1$ at the $i$th coordinate and is $0$ for all other coordinates. Consider multiplication by $e_i$ - it kills off almost everything! Consider what it doesn't kill off, and how this relates to projections

Comment: So if we had a 3x3 matrix would these be the values for e_1, e_1, e_3?

https://imgur.com/a/u73cQos

Comment: yes. That is correct

Comment: Thank you so very much. I was making it way way harder then it needed to be. Thank you again and again!

Comment: no problem at all :) let me know if you have any more questions on this matter.